# How to automatically reload TYPO3 calendar from external ics

Tags: calendar, typo3, cal

Hi I'm using the calendar base extension (cal) for displaying my calendar in a TYPO3 website.

I configured an external calendar and it imports all events correctly. How can I automatically reload the events from this external ics-calendar?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For TYPO3 4.3 and up, you'll want to use the scheduler extension. Once its installed, you'll find a task inside the scheduler module for updating external calendars.